# jquery click event not firing in IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here, this below code works in Chrome & Firefox but does not work in IE and Edge.  Any help much apprciated, its driving me round the bend.

using the following jquery versions:-

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var bindEvents = function(mutations)
    {   
        // editUserBtn click event
        $('.editUserBtn').off('click').click(function(e)
        {
            currentThis = this;
            
            var userId = $(currentThis).closest(".userTbl tr").find(".userId").text();          
            var userIdTrim = $.trim(userId);

            var userType = $(currentThis).closest(".userTbl tr").find(".userType").text();          
            var userTypeTrim = $.trim(userType);
            
            $eb.executeFunctionAsynchronously(function() { /*success*/ }, function() { /*failure*/ }, 'editUser', {id: parseInt(userIdTrim,10),
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                type: userTypeTrim}, true);
        });
    };

    var observer = new MutationObserver(bindEvents);
    observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true});
});
```

Comment: Assuming you mean IE11 not earlier, MutationObserver should be ok: https://caniuse.com/#search=MutationObserver

Comment: Why a mutation observer? You're not even using `mutations` o.O Did I miss something or why don't you just use event delegation?

Comment: Yes IE 11, the above code does not work.

Comment: Its some legacy code I have taken on, what should I use instead?

Comment: Ok, looks like it's waiting for changes to the body, then reapplying a click event to `.editUserBtn` - get rid of bindEvents and observer and change the `.off().click()` to `$(document).on("click", ".editUserBtn", function(e) {...` - event delegation

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/